# Facebook Adset Creation Fails for Messenger Ad on a Carousel Creative

Tags: facebook, facebook-marketing-api

I'm creating an adset via posting to `adsets` endpoint (Marketing API).
It is returning me the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error occurred",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1,
    "error_subcode": 1815652,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Missing Messenger Destination in Child Item",
    "error_user_msg": "To use Messenger as destination, all children     items in the carousel ads should have messenger destination.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AdulKVKescc"
  }
}
```

The creative is a *carousel*.
Each of the children (cards) of the carousel has got proper `call_to_action`, which is `'{type:"LEARN_MORE",value:{app_destination:"MESSENGER"}}'`

I've tried various combinations of putting `link` and not putting a `link` in the child elements. I also tried putting a m.me link, but that throws a different error while creating the creative itself.

I'm using `adcreatives` endpoint to create my creatives...

Any guidelines on what should be the link value be? Facebook Documentation says it is ignored. If ignored, why the error?

Answer (score 2):

The error is a bit misleading, because the child_attachments all contain the call_to_action, but you must also add the same call_to_action to the creative in link_data or video_data (depending on type of creative).

Answer (score 0):

Add call_to_action to link_data. *Credit Chris Simmons*

```
# use picture or image_hash
fb_dummy_image = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eGKWS6_187s/maxresdefault.jpg'
image_hash = "164d943385c130d64e702664c9ab1798"

data = {
    "access_token": SELLIO_AD_SERVER_TOKEN,
    "name": "Sample Creative",
    "object_story_spec": {
        "link_data": {
        "call_to_action": {"type": "LEARN_MORE", "value": {"app_destination": "MESSENGER"}},
            "child_attachments": [
                {
                    "description": "$800.99",
                    "image_hash": image_hash,
                    "link": "https://www.example.com",
                    "name": "A1",
                    "call_to_action": {
                        "type": "LEARN_MORE",
                        "value": {
                            "app_destination": "MESSENGER",
                        }
                    },
                },
                {
                    "description": "$400.99",
                    "image_hash": image_hash,
                    "link": "https://www.example.com",
                    "name": "A2",
                    "call_to_action": {
                        "type": "LEARN_MORE",
                        "value": {
                            "app_destination": "MESSENGER",
                        }
                    },
                },
                {
                    "description": "$300.99",
                    "picture": fb_dummy_image,
                    "link": "https://www.messenger.com/t/xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "name": "A3",
                    "call_to_action": {
                        "type": "LEARN_MORE",
                        "value": {
                            "app_destination": "MESSENGER",
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "link": "https://www.messenger.com/t/xxxxxxxxxx",
            "page_welcome_message": '{"user_edit": true, "message": {"attachment": {"type": "template", "payload": {"template_type": "generic", "elements": [{"buttons": [{"url": "http://www.example.com/", "type": "web_url", "title": "View Website"}, {"type": "postback", "payload": "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD", "title": "Start Chatting"}], "subtitle": "Optional: Enter a subtitle to provide more information", "image_url": "https://image.ibb.co/bz5t6Q/placeholder.png", "title": "Enter a title to accompany your image"}, {"buttons": [{"url": "http://www.example.com/", "type": "web_url", "title": "View Website"}, {"type": "postback", "payload": "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD", "title": "Start Chatting"}], "subtitle": "2nd product", "image_url": "https://image.ibb.co/bz5t6Q/placeholder.png", "title": "a2"}, {"buttons": [{"url": "http://www.example.com/", "type": "web_url", "title": "View Website"}, {"type": "postback", "payload": "USER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD", "title": "Start Chatting"}], "subtitle": "3rd product", "image_url": "https://image.ibb.co/bz5t6Q/placeholder.png", "title": "a3"}]}}}}'
        },
        "page_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
}
```

Then also make an ad campaign with **MESSAGES** as the objective

```
def create_campaign(ad_account_id, campaign_name):
my_account = AdAccount(ad_account_id)
campaign = Campaign(parent_id=my_account.get_id_assured())

campaign.update({
    Campaign.Field.name: campaign_name,
    Campaign.Field.objective: 'MESSAGES'
})

campaign.remote_create(params={
    'status': Campaign.Status.paused,
})
logging.debug(campaign)
return campaign.get_id()
```